# Get data from dynamically created controls in TemplateFields for gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a webpage that has a gridview which is bound to a list of custom objects but also has 1 dynamically created TemplateFields. These fields are created at Page_PreRender and can be a textbox or dropdownlist based on the object in the list. I have a button at the bottom of the page that needs to save all the data inputed in the dynamic objects when pressed. When i try to find the dynamic control i am unable to do so using the FindControl() method. It always comes back blank.

How can i retrieve the user entered/selected data?

This is my gridview

```
<div id="divSearchCriteriaGrid" runat="server" class="padding-top-15">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvSearchCriteria" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvSearchCriteria_OnRowDataBound" GridLines="None">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SearchFieldId" Visible="False" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Search Field">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDisplay" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" onclick="ToggleCriteriaControls(this)" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="25%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Begin Criteria">
                                <ItemStyle Width="35%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Criteria">
                                <ItemStyle Width="35%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ControlTypeId" Visible="False" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
```

And this is my code behind for creating the controls:

```
public void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TryAction(PrepareLoad);
    }
private void PrepareLoad()
    {
        if (IsPostBack) return;
        BindData(); 
    }
private void BindData()
    {
        gvSearchCriteria.DataSource = null;
        gvSearchCriteria.DataSource = SearchFieldList;
        gvSearchCriteria.DataBind();
    } 
protected void gvSearchCriteria_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            SearchField searchField = e.Row.DataItem as SearchField;
            if (searchField != null)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = searchField.SearchFieldId.ToString();
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = searchField.ControlTypeId.ToString();

                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbDisplay");
                checkBox.Text = searchField.FieldDescription;
                checkBox.Checked = searchField.Checked;
                checkBox.Enabled = true;

                if (searchField.ControlTypeId.ToString() == "1")
                {
                    RadTextBox textBox = new RadTextBox();
                    textBox.ID = "txtBoxBegin";
                    e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(textBox);

                    textBox = new RadTextBox();
                    textBox.ID = string.Format("txt{0}End", searchField.SearchFieldId);
                    e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(textBox);

                }
                else if (searchField.ControlTypeId.ToString() == "2")
                {
                    RadComboBox comboBox = new RadComboBox();
                    comboBox = new SearchService().GetRadComboBoxById(searchField.SearchFieldId);
                    comboBox.ID = string.Format("cbo{0}Begin", searchField.SearchFieldId);
                    e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(comboBox);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This all works good and the controls get created with the checkbox.
Here is my code for trying to loop through each row of the gridview to get the user entered data which does not work.

```
private void Save()
    {
       foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSearchCriteria.Rows)
       {
           CheckBox include = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbDisplay");
           int id, controlTypeId;
           string criteriaOne = string.Empty;
           string criteriaTwo = string.Empty;
           if (!include.Checked) continue;

           id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);
           if (controlTypeId == "1")
           {
               RadTextBox radTextBox = (RadTextBox) row.FindControl("txtBoxBegin");
               if (radTextBox != null)
               {
                   criteriaOne = radTextBox.Text;
               }

               radTextBox = (RadTextBox)row.FindControl("txtBoxEnd");
               if (radTextBox != null)
               {
                   criteriaTwo = radTextBox.Text;
               }

           }
           else if(controlTypeId == "2")
           {
               RadComboBox radComboBox = (RadComboBox)row.FindControl(string.Format("cbo{0}Begin",id));
               if (radComboBox != null)
               {
                   criteriaOne = radComboBox.SelectedValue;
               }
           }
       } 
    }
```

The radTextBox and radComboBox variables i am trying to get using the FindControlId always comes back null.
cell 0 comes back ok each time with the correct Id. the cbDisplay checkbox always returns whether the row is checked or not and cell 4 gets the ControlTypeId just fine. It is the TemplateFields that i cannot get the values for.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the information from the dynamic controls once i moved the BindData() function to the Page_Init instead of the Page_PreRender().